# OpenCV: Cannot make Matrix with Negative Numbers

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, matrix

I am using OpenCV 2.2 on MS Visual C++ 2010 on Windows 7.  32 bit application.

I am trying to make the following matrix. [-1 0 1].

I try

```
cv::Mat Kernel = cv::Mat::zeros(1, 3, CV_8S );

Kernel.data[0] = -1;

Kernel.data[2] = 1;
```

I get `[255 0  1]`.

I get the same result regardless of what I replace CV_8S with.

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Peter

Comment: Are you sure it isn't just being displayed as an `unsigned byte`?

Comment: According to the MSVS watch window, it is giving me a data type of unsigned char * so -1 ->255.  I don't know why CV_8S gives me unsigned.  Thank you for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the data member of `cv::Mat` is in fact `uchar*` and not `char*` regardless of the actual matrix type (i.e. `CV_8U`), **I guess** you print the values by iterating over `kernel.data` without casting data from `uchar*` to `char*` (or checking them with watch without doing the same) and that why you cant see negative number.

Additionally, you have a nicer syntax to achieve the same

```
cv::Mat kernel = (cv::Mat_<char>(1,3) << -1, 0, -1);
```

Comment: the best way to work in such situations is to create a separate pointer var, same type as the matrix, and use it. `char* dataPtr = (char*)kernel.data` Then, printing/modifying is straitforward/

Comment: what if I need dynamic rows and columns?